# How to fix: 'Adding Face API to the project failed'

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I'm trying to add Face API connected service to a C# web application but while the service is 'Creating new Face API...' I get the error: Adding Face API to the project failed: The 'properties' fied is invalid,  error: 'Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Boolean'. Path 'isMigrated'.'.

I have updated my versions of .NET and vs 2017. Created new projects with no luck. Current project is a completely new one with nothing altered. I'm using a trial  Azure Account. The issue seems to be with the implementation of Face API as 'isMigrated' does not appear anywhere in my code so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error just same to yours while I followed this [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/vs-face-connected-service).I am not sure if there is something wrong with component in vs maybe something like a bug.

I did some research on it and found that all this connected service do is creating an Face API service in your subscription and write the API key and endpoint in your web application `appsettings.json` file. In fact, we can finish this process manually.

These are the steps that I made the demo work on my side :

1. Go to [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com), create a Face API cognitive service

[image]
[image]
After the service be created , copy its key and endpoint here : 
[image]

2. Create a .net core web app in VS, replace content in
   `appsettings.json` with content below :

```html
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "FaceAPI_ServiceKey": "<key in previous step>",
      "FaceAPI_ServiceEndPoint": "<endpoint in previous step>"
    }
```

replace the content in startup.cs with code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace <your name space here>
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private IConfiguration configuration;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // TODO: Change this to your image's path on your site.
            string imagePath = @"images/face1.jpg";

            // Enable static files such as image files.
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            string faceApiKey = this.configuration["FaceAPI_ServiceKey"];
            string faceApiEndPoint = this.configuration["FaceAPI_ServiceEndPoint"];

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            // Request headers.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", faceApiKey);

            // Request parameters. A third optional parameter is "details".
            string requestParameters = "returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise";

            // Assemble the URI for the REST API Call.
            string uri = faceApiEndPoint + "/detect?" + requestParameters;

            // Request body. Posts an image you've added to your site's images folder.
            var fileInfo = env.WebRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo(imagePath);
            var byteData = GetImageAsByteArray(fileInfo.PhysicalPath);

            string contentStringFace = string.Empty;
            using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
            {
                // This example uses content type "application/octet-stream".
                // The other content types you can use are "application/json" and "multipart/form-data".
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                // Execute the REST API call.
                var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;

                // Get the JSON response.
                contentStringFace = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Returns the contents of the specified file as a byte array.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="imageFilePath">The image file to read.</param>
            /// <returns>The byte array of the image data.</returns>
            static byte[] GetImageAsByteArray(string imageFilePath)
            {
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
                return binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Formats the given JSON string by adding line breaks and indents.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="json">The raw JSON string to format.</param>
            /// <returns>The formatted JSON string.</returns>
            static string JsonPrettyPrint(string json)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
                    return string.Empty;

                json = json.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace("\t", "");

                string INDENT_STRING = "    ";
                var indent = 0;
                var quoted = false;
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (var i = 0; i < json.Length; i++)
                {
                    var ch = json[i];
                    switch (ch)
                    {
                        case '{':
                        case '[':
                            sb.Append(ch);
                            if (!quoted)
                            {
                                sb.AppendLine();
                            }
                            break;
                        case '}':
                        case ']':
                            if (!quoted)
                            {
                                sb.AppendLine();
                            }
                            sb.Append(ch);
                            break;
                        case '"':
                            sb.Append(ch);
                            bool escaped = false;
                            var index = i;
                            while (index > 0 && json[--index] == '\\')
                                escaped = !escaped;
                            if (!escaped)
                                quoted = !quoted;
                            break;
                        case ',':
                            sb.Append(ch);
                            if (!quoted)
                            {
                                sb.AppendLine();
                            }
                            break;
                        case ':':
                            sb.Append(ch);
                            if (!quoted)
                                sb.Append(" ");
                            break;
                        default:
                            sb.Append(ch);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<p><b>Face Image:</b></p>");
                await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<div><img src=\"" + imagePath + "\" /></div>");
                await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<p><b>Face detection API results:</b></p>");
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("<p>");
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonPrettyPrint(contentStringFace));
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("<p>");
            });

        }
    }
}
```

add a folder under wwwroot and place a image here, in this case ,the image name is `face1.jpg`:
[image]

With these steps done , run the project you can see it works perfectly as the official demo indicated : 
[image]

If this post is helpful, pls click on big gray check button on this answer left side to mark this answer ,so that it will help others who have the same issue :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I've tried what you said but I'm getting a few errors, the main one being with IServiceCollection but I believe this is because I am running vs 2017, the IServiceCollection.AddRazorPages() documentation say it required 2019 so I'm updating that as well as updating .NET to 3.0.100

Comment: VS and .NET updated, now works, Thanks for your help!